# How to create list of all parts of elements in NumPy array (Python list)

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have a NumPy array (or Python list) with different length string elements:

```
array(['*,V*,UV,**,a2*,IR' , 'SB*,SB*,V*,UV,**,*,a2*,IR' , '*,V*,a2*' , ...])
```

Each element is a set of abbreviations separated by comma. How to find all different abbreviations and their count in the entire array (list)? In other words, I need something like this:

In my array V* are found 5 times, IR - 7 times, etc. Shortest answer is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) with a generator expression:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> lis = ['*,V*,UV,**,a2*,IR' , 'SB*,V*,UV,**,*,a2*,IR' , '*,V*,a2*']
>>> Counter(y for x in lis for y in x.split(',') if '*' in y)
Counter({'V*': 3, '*': 3, 'a2*': 3, '**': 2, 'SB*': 1})
```

Note that if by abbreviation you meant [glob pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29) then all array items are actually valid glob patterns, but currently I am only counting those patterns that contain at least a single `'*'`.  You can remove the `if '*' in y` part if such filtering is not required.

Comment: I need to count all abbreviations (V*, IR, etc.) I have corrected my question.

Comment: @user2579566 As I already mentioned in answer, you can remove the `if` condition to fix that.

Comment: What to do if I have two equal abbreviations in the elements? I need to count only once in this case.

Comment: @user2579566 For example?

Comment: two SB* in my second element 'SB*,SB*,V*,UV,**,*,a2*,IR'

Comment: @user2579566 Use `set`: `... set(x.split(',')) ...`

Answer (score 1):

Your 'V*' appears 3 times, not 5...

use `collections.Counter`, `join` the string list and then `split` it:

```
In [755]: ar=array(['*,V*,UV,**,a2*,IR' , 'SB*,V*,UV,**,*,a2*,IR' , '*,V*,a2*' ])

In [756]: from collections import Counter

In [757]: Counter(','.join(ar).split(','))
Out[757]: Counter({'*': 3, 'V*': 3, 'a2*': 3, 'UV': 2, 'IR': 2, '**': 2, 'SB*': 1})
```

Comment: My 'V*' appears 157 times. My array (list) consist of several hundreds elements (see ', ...' at the end of the array).

Comment: @user2579566, I mean, in your demo ;)